# Grab specific text from string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I grab the invite code from this string?
`{awarded:1,inviteURL:https:\/\/www.example.com\/refer\/invite\/111A111A\/}`

The expected output would be "111A111A".
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Should we consider it as a string or json or dictionary?

Comment: @AppajiChintimi Consider it a string

Comment: Have you attempted to write any code to solve the problem? If so, please add it to the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried it in a simple way, You could give more details for further improvement.

```
s = "{awarded:1,inviteURL:https:\/\/www.example.com\/refer\/invite\/111A111A\/}"

print(s[-11: -3])
```

Comment: -11 to -3? What if I change the string?

Comment: *You could give more details for further improvement.* - please ask this before posting the answer to write better quality answers.

Comment: That's why I said, It can be improved if more details were given.

Comment: Thanks @AppajiChintimi this works perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

This will do it with ReGex

```
import re

def findInvite(s):
    return re.search(r"(?<=/invite\\/).*(?=\\/)",s).group()

assert findInvite("{awarded:1,inviteURL:https:\/\/www.example.com\/refer\/invite\/111A111A\/}") == "111A111A"
```

And if this isn't a string but a dict, then change the function to:

```
def findInvite(d):
    s = d["inviteURL"]
    return re.search(r"(?<=/invite\\/).*(?=\\/)",s).group()
```